# why output is different when data member of class is changed to reference

Tags: c++

Following program is giving the output as expected

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class test 
{
  string name; // non-referance
  public:
    test(string name1 = "default") :name (name1) {  cout << name << "  is constructed"<< endl;}
    ~test() { cout << name << " is destructed"<<endl;}
};
int main()
{
 test t1("Mike");
 test t2;
}
```

OUTPUT:   As expected

```
Mike is constructed
default is constructed
default is destructed
Mike is destructed
```

When  data member "name " is changed into reference variable, output is different( when both object are destructed,  " name"  values ("Mike" and "default") from output is gone , why?

```
class test 
{
  string &name; // **Make it reference**
  public:
    test(string name1 = "default") :name (name1) {  cout << name << "  is constructed"<< endl;}
    ~test() { cout << name << " is destructed"<<endl;}
};
```

OUTPUT: "Mike" and "default" are missing

```
Mike is constructed
default is constructed
is destructed
is destrcuted
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `name1` parameter is local to the `test` constructor.  It goes out of scope and is destroyed when the `test` constructor exits.

When `name` is not declared to be a reference, it is an actual `string` object whose lifetime is that of its containing `test` object. It **copies** data from `name1` when initialized.  As such, when `name` is used later in the `test` destructor, it is still a valid object with its own data, and you see the output you are expecting.

When `name` is declared to be a reference instead, it is not an object of its own, it is bound to the `name1` object (it becomes an alias for `name1`), and is thus left dangling when `name1` is destroyed.  As such, when `name` is used later in the `test` destructor, it is no longer referring to a valid `string` object, and the code has **undefined behavior**.

The only way to make the latter case work correctly is to have `name1` also be a reference to some external `string` that remains valid for the lifetime of the `test` object, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class test 
{
  string &name;
  public:
    test(string &name1) :name (name1) {  cout << name << "  is constructed" << endl; }
    ~test() { cout << name << " is destructed" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
  string name1 = "Mike";
  test t1(name1);

  string name2 = "default";
  test t2(name2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks@Remy Lebeau., What code needs to be change if we want to get the same output as when  data member is used as non -reference

Comment: If you declare `name` to be a reference, you have to bind it to *something* that stays valid for the lifetime of the reference. In this example, there is no reason whatsoever for `name` to be a reference at all.